# Import error. Can't import kmeans_plusplus

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm trying to replicate an example of a clustering model with scikit-learn:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

Returns:

```
'0.23.2'
```

And:

```
from sklearn.cluster import kmeans_plusplus
```

Returns the Error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'kmeans_plusplus' from 'sklearn.cluster' (C:\Users\sddss\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.kmeans_plusplus.html), `kmeans_plusplus` is

> *New in version 0.24.*

so it is not available for the version 0.23.2 you are using.

Nevertheless, this should not be a real issue; the only difference between the "good old" K-Means already available in scikit-learn is the initialization of the cluster centers according to the kmeans++ algorithm; and this is already available in the standard KMeans. From the [standard KMeans documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans) regarding the `init` argument:

> 'k-means++' : selects initial cluster centers for k-mean clustering in a smart way to speed up convergence

So, what you need to do instead  is simply to use the "vanilla" KMeans of scikit-learn with the argument `init='kmeans++'`:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, init='kmeans++')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `kmeans_plusplus` class or module for version `0.23.2`. You need to import `KMeans` and set the `init` key word argument to `kmeans++` to obtain the behaviour you want

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++')
```

Comment: There is, since v0.24: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.kmeans_plusplus.html

Comment: My bad, deleting the answer.